# Is this a layered architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, service, architecture, layered

I am having a confusion while mapping my software design with an architectural pattern.

the below diagram describes my proposition.
[image]

What I wanted to ask is -

1. Is the third layer really a layer, or just a constituent part of layer 2?
2. The fourth layer constitutes of those resources for which all my software is built. They are the things, which do not provide service as such, but for which all the work is done, on which all the work is done. Are they to be included in architectural description?

Comment: The image is far too small, cannot make out anything at all.

Comment: well, i clicked the link http://s20.postimg.org/gjuxkg0al/for_stack_overflow.png just right now its resolution is quite large.are you sure your browser is not displaying the zoomed out image?

Comment: Looks fine now, perhaps was re-uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer is not an exact term, it can be customized per your needs.
That said, I would organize your design a bit different:

- Your third layer is actually a side layer/package that provides services to your main software flows but doesn't have an active role in them. More appropriate would be to put it alongside the 2 first layers that can interact with the required services per need.
- Fourth layer indeed shouldn't be part of your design because it's actually a description of entities outside your system. You can outline the interfaces to these entities but they do not consitute layer in your system.

You may also take a look at a more formal approach for design depicting - check the [Package diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_diagram) in UML and [Layer diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409462.aspx) (not standard but close to what you look for).

Comment: The problem here is that, the third layer(tools and services) is used only by the second layer(Command API) and not by the GUI. I introduced second layer to hide details of services and tools from the GUI. My design follows a strict top to bottom communication flow as in TCP/IP protocol suite. Plus, I cannot treat the third layer as a side component, since all my functionality is eventually performed by this services/tools layer, and it is allways required for every operation. You are right bout the fourth layer i think, that should clear by doubts about it

Comment: If tools and services are only for second layer than indeed it's probably better to include it as part of second layer. Keeping the correct scope is important

Comment: I also thought so. But then, every layer is meant just for its upper layer according to the layered architecture pattern. Even the second layer is used by GUI layer only. I though initially of grouping second and third layers as one single layer, since the tools and services didn't have any unifying theme/interface over them. But then, even in TCP/IP protocol suite, there are multiple protocols to choose from at each layer, which are independent from each other. Also, in case of APIs, the app programming interface layer encapsulates the lower layers of frequently used functionality.

Comment: Like I wrote above - layer isn't an exact term. A healthy layering would be one where each layer participates in a usecase and has the same level of details. Interfaces between different layers should be well-defined (again at the same level of details). If we take your TCP/IP example - choosing the specific protocol is an internal responsibility inside the layer, as far as your layers diagram is considered, the operation is "do your thing according to relevant protocol" - that's what I call being on the same level of details.

Comment: Thanks mate. "do your thing according to relevant protocol" - This really cleared things up for me. And now, I will have to find out the internal architectural pattern for this newly combined "second+third" layer. I think maybe instead of using facade, multiple adapters will be appropriate for communicating with the different types of tools and scripts.